# Parsing HTML tables with different divisions at same time to write on listview

Tags: vb.net, parsing, html-table, html-agility-pack, listviewitem

trying to read the data from the html table which are located in different divisions but could not get it simultaneously ( parsing starting with the first table and jumps to second which i need to read at the same level row data together )

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim web As New HtmlWeb
    Dim docmech As HtmlDocument = web.Load("http://www.eurovent-certification.com/en/Certified_products/Access_by_programme.php?lg=en&rub=04&srub=01&select_prog=AHU&select_partic=664&select_marque=YORK&select_class=MB+%2F+MB+%2F+MECH")
    Dim MechNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = docmech.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table/tr/td[2]/table[6]/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/table//nobr[a[@class='certificat-pdf']] | /html/body/table/tr/td[2]/table[6]/tr[1]/td[2]/div[3]/table//td[@class='tabGrisClair > normal']")
    Dim ColumnCount As Integer = 1
    Dim TempListItem As New ListViewItem


    If Not IsNothing(MechNodes) Then

        For Each item As HtmlNode In MechNodes
            If item.Name = "nobr" And item.InnerText <> "" And item.Attributes.Count = 0 Then
                Dim Name As String = item.InnerText.Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbTab, "").Replace("&nbsp;", "")
                TempListItem = ListView1.Items.Add(Name)

            Else
                If item.Attributes("class").Value = "tabGrisClair > normal" Then

                    Dim SubName As String = item.InnerText.Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbTab, "")
                    TempListItem = ListView1.Items.Add(SubName)
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End If
```

Xpath information of the tables ;

- 1st table located at second div and row number starting from 4 to 10 and 1 column )

/html/body/table/tr/td[2]/table[6]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/table/tr[4]/td/nobr ---> PU3055 (Target Text)

- 2nd table located at third div and row number starting from 4 to 10 but 14 columns )

/html/body/table/tr/td[2]/table[6]/tr[1]/td[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2] ---> D1(M) (Target Text)

**How can i add the data's of both table at the same listview (with the same row number shown in the web page?**

I am getting result as this ;[Parsing result from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh8SW.png)

instead of the target result as :
[Target result from the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3Dbr.png)

Comment: Explain better what happens and what you want to happen.

Comment: The xpath is reading the first table until the end of the rows then start reading to second table which i need to read them simultaneously both table and get the data

Comment: That's normal, and I meant what data you get compared to what data you want to get.

Comment: @CruleD edited question with target and result screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do it would be two for each loops.

After you add models (items), loop over them or something similar then add columns (subitems).

15 lines in total for everything.
[image]
Alternatively you could create two collections (A and B), then read one by one from each (like A1, B1, A2, B2...etc).

Complete:
[image]

Comment: And hi again, I noticed that website looked familiar to me.

Comment: Hi Again, 2nd for each loops for subitems is starting from the last row of the items and get only 1 row data, how to start writing from the first row of the table which has been filled with the 1st loop

Comment: You are right, i have started my first parsing experience (&started to learning xpath) as per your recommendation for this website before @cruleD

Comment: cant get the same result, i would appreciate if you could give me one step more details especially for two loop alternate; my last try something like this                  For Each / Get items / Next / For Each / get subitems / Next

Comment: The way I did it was: grabbed collection of rows (that table that contains Dm1...etc), starting with third row , then parsed each td (cell) inside tr (row).

Comment: The sounds look like to me a space technology:) Still googling to find similar codes for the way you provided:( ..

Comment: No need to google, just think about it. Look how the website looks (what you have), look at what you need then implement a solution. I believe you problem is not understanding what you need to do, not the code. Eg you have a 1 and 2, but you do not understand that you need to do 1+2 to get 3.

Comment: I missed your picture while commented.. sorry, thanks for the solution

Comment: If it would make it easier to you, try getting both parts independently first. Then work on a solution how to combine them to get it the way you need. I mean, I could give you the code, but that's a bear favor. Understanding what you need from a logical/tehnical standpoint is more important than actually knowing what code the write, actually you can't even write without knowing first.

Comment: Actually i got 1 and 2 separately hours ago but i have stacked to add 2 while it pasted to last row of the list item in order to get 3. Spent hours to get solution just for add 2 to listview row1 / column 2

Comment: And how did you do it?